# Delete rows with a certain value in Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete rows who have certain values. The values that I want to delete have a **"+"** and are as follows:

**cooperative+parallel**
**passive+prosocial**

My dataset consists of 900000 rows, and about 2000 values contain the problem I mentioned.

I want the code something like this:

`df = df[df.columnname != '+']`

The above is for one column (its not working well) but I would also like one example for whole dataset.

I prefer the solution in Pandas.

Many thanks

Comment: `df = df[~df.columnname.str.contains('+')]`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with invert mask by `~` and escape `+`, because special regex character with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for all object columns selected by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one match:

```
df1 = df[~df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\+')).any(axis=1)]
```

Or use `regex=False`:

```
df1 = df[~df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\+', regex=False)).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for one column. Could you please provide me an example for the full dataset also?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[~df['columnname'].str.contains('+', regex=False)]
```

documentation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html